# VB .Net List of object in list of object

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a program that marries two objects in a list of objects which meet the conditions.

My problem is the second list of married object doesn't display correctly and I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong.

Here is my code. I have this class with properties, etc:

```
Public Class Gallo
    Dim taquilla As Integer
    Dim libras As Integer
    Dim onzas As Integer
    Dim puya As Integer
    Dim tuerto As Boolean
    Dim puntos As Decimal
    Dim excluir(3) As Integer
```

With this class I compare those values and if two of them meet the conditions I want to add these two objects to another class called `Married`

```
Public Class Casados
    Dim casado1 As Gallo
    Dim casado2 As Gallo

    Public Sub New(casado1 As Gallo, casado2 As Gallo)
        Me.casado1 = casado1
        Me.casado2 = casado2
    End Sub

    Public Property casado1P
        Get
            Return casado1
        End Get
        Set(value)
            casado1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property casado2P
        Get
            Return casado2
        End Get
        Set(value)
            casado2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I make a list of that class called `casados`

```
Private misCasados As New List(Of Casados)
```

Then when two objects meet the conditions I add to that list and show them in a datagridview.

```
                If diferenciaTotal < 2 And diferenciaTotal > -2 Then
                    Dim casados As Casados
                    casados = New Casados(misGallos(i), misGallos(j))
                    misCasados.Add(casados)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i

dataCasados.DataSource = ""
dataCasados.DataSource = misCasados
For i = 0 To misCasados.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine(misCasados(i))
Next
```

The problem is that the information displayed in datagridview is just `Gallos.Gallo` (names of class) not the information I want. I want to show what objects married and show the id `Taquilla` to know who they are.

Comment: You should configure DataGridView to display properties of `Casados` class, see: [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Still doesnt work is shows name class not id i want. http://prntscr.com/q2kbz9 see this image

Comment: The code you show for the Gallo class does not have a single Property, only Private fields.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: You need expose properties of `Gallo` you want to display as properties on `Casados` class

Comment: You need to provide a datatype for your Properties.

Comment: how to do this? I have all the property in class `Gallo` public

Comment: `Gallo` has no properties, only fields

Comment: @JezZu A property has the keyword Property in the declaration. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-create-a-property

Answer (score 0):

You should configure DataGridView to display properties of `Gallo` class through `Casados` class.

`DataGridView` binding recognise only properties (public fields will not be displayed), for example class `Gallo` on it own can not be displayed, unless you convert all fields into a properties.

```
Option Strict On ' This is "must have"

Public Class Casados
    Private _first As Gallo
    Private _second As Gallo

    Public Sub New(first As Gallo, second As Gallo)
        _first = first
        _second = second
    End Sub

    Public Property TaquillaOfFirst As Integer
        Get
            Return _first.taquilla
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _first.taquilla = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TaquillaOfSecond As Integer
        Get
            Return _second.taquilla
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _second.taquilla = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Configure columns of `DataGridView` to display properties  `TaquillaOfFirst` and `TaquillaOfSecond`

Notice that line `dataCasados.DataSource = ""` is redundant, feel free to remove it.

Not related but

```
If diferenciaTotal < 2 AndAlso diferenciaTotal > -2 Then
    Dim casados As New Casados(misGallos(i), misGallos(j))
    misCasados.Add(casados)
End If
```

When you set `Option Strict` to `On` you will start benefit from compiler help, which will recognise possible type errors.

Comment: `first.taquilla = value` should be `_first.taquilla = value`

Comment: Option Strict requires that Properties have datatypes. Also value in the Set needs a datatype.